# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.doLastPhaseActions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, flash-scope

I have about 3 apps in glassfish-4 using SingleSignOn for security and a 4th app for 'Access Control' where all the users for all the apps login and get redirected to any of the apps the user has access to. Everything has been working perfectly until now that i need to add a 5th app. And the 5th app refused to work with the others.
here is the code snippet i used in the first in all the apps:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SecurityController
// unnecessary codes ommitted

String email = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();

if(email==null){
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
.redirect("http://localhost:8080/AccessControl/login.xhtml")
}
```

This has been working for me in all the first 3 apps but wouldnt work in this last one. Am using standard Java EE 6 with primefaces 5.0.

Here is the error i get:

```
Warning:   Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.doLastPhaseActions(ELFlash.java:644)
at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.doPostPhaseActions(ELFlash.java:582)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.doLastPhaseActions(ExternalContextImpl.java:1081)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:643)
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated as this is delaying a long due move to production. Thanks

Comment: Which Mojarra version? Tried latest? When exactly are you trying to redirect? Inside @PostConstruct or preRenderView? Nonetheless, this authentication checking job belongs in a servlet filter, not in a managed bean.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC am redirecting in a preRenderView method and using Mojarra 2.2.0. And when i broke down the code line i discovered the error NullPointerException happened at the point when the method .redirect("URL") was called beacuse the externalContext was not null.

Comment: 2.2.0 is ancient. Try latest then we can exclude an already long fixed bug from being the cause.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, i changed to Mojarra 2.2.9 downloaded from [here](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.9/)  but still getting same stack trace. I must say i left out this (below) as part of my stack trace.

    `Severe:   JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming     cookie value 81KjRK0%3D.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request`.

I dont know if it will help. Thanks alot

Comment: Could be a dirty cookie from a previous deployment. Clean cookies and retry.